# How to Deactivate Fonts From the Font Catalogue

Tags: fonts, texlive, typography

For example, if I want to use https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/royalinitialen/ on the first letter of a story I'm writing, but every other letter afterward to be the default font. How can I go about this? This is what I have, and it produces a Royal T and nothing else (because Royal only admits capitalized letters):

```
\initfamily{T}he car was delivered to the appropriate address
```

Comment: \initfamily is a switch, it stays active until the current group ends. Place it inside the braces, not outside of them.

Comment: Expanding on Marcel's good comment: `{\initfamilyT}he car was delivered to the appropriate address.`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner...with a space between `\initfamily` and `T`.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Ah, thanks. Silly me!

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thank you so much, this turned out to be the most practical solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the “command form” rather than the “declaration form”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{RoyalIn.fd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\royalfamily}{\usefont{U}{RoyalIn}{xl}{n}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textroyal}{\royalfamily}

\begin{document}

\textroyal{T}he car was delivered

\end{document}
```

[image]